# How to fake a browser resize of 1px and bring it back to what it was?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have a script that only seem to start when I resized the browser. I can't find out why and start to be short on time. So i was wondering if I could simulate the browser to resize after the page load to it could fire the script and then bring the browser resolution back to what it was.

Is this possible ?

**edit**

Ok now the script work if I load the page from a link in the menu, but fails if I click the browser's refresh button.

Comment: Why is the script started when you resize the browser? Figure out that reason and post the code. Trying to force it to do something that it wasn't designed to do is a good way to cause yourself a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just trigger the `resize` event:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).resize();
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm calling and it's working by the carouFredSel don't fire onload... only when I resize. Weird